# I can't open my ipad mini. Please send help :((

Tags: ipad

I have jailbroken my ipad mini months ago. 2 weeks ago i decided to erase all data. I didnt turn off anything i just went to general and deleted all data. I waited for my ipad to restart but it didnt. Its been days now, but still i cant open my ipad. Only an apple logo appears with a bar below that doesnt seem to have any progress. I did everything, charged my device, waited until its battery is dead then charge it again but same apple logo appears. What do I do? :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried entering iTunes recovery mode (turning it off then plugging it in and holding the home button at the same time) then restoring it?

Comment: Note you will need iTunes on a mac/pc to do this.